# Android Application works correctly on emulator but crashes on real device

Tags: java, android, web-services, emulation, device

I'm developing an android application which use MySQL database and json, it works on emulator correctly but when im launching it on my device (Galaxy S5) I'm facing a force close 
Here is my request to server and get json objects:

```
    btnFaalSazi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String validatePhoneNumber = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            if (validatePhoneNumber.matches("^(?:0\\d{10}|9\\d{9})$")) {

                txtError.setText("");
                structUsers.register_number = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
                String phone = structUsers.register_number;

                Log.i("LOG", phone);
                Log.i("LOG", "HELOOOOOO");

                final ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("register_number", phone));

                String result = Webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.10.110:2233/api/register", params);

                if (result != null) {
                    try {
                        G.users.clear();
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                        String status = object.optString("status");
                        String code = object.optString("code");
                        String message = object.optString("message");

                        Log.i("LOG", "status hast " + status);
                        Log.i("LOG", "code hast  " + code);
                        Log.i("LOG", "mesage hast  " + message);

                        if (status != null && code != null) {
                            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == -1) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityRegisterNumber.this, ActivityRegisterCode.class);
                                intent.putExtra("REGISTERNUMBER", structUsers.register_number);
                                ActivityRegisterNumber.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }

                        if (status != null && message != null) {
                            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 100) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("LOG", "after error 100");
                            } else if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 101) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("LOG", "after error 101");
                            } else if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 102) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("LOG", "after error 102");
                            } else if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 103) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("LOG", "after error 103");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                txtError.setText("Wrong phone number");
            }

        }
    });
```

I think application crashes when its going to perform this line :

```
                    String result = Webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.10.110:2233/api/register", params);
```

and this is my webservice module :

```
public class Webservice {

public static String readUrl(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

        if (params != null) {
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        }

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);

        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        return result;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}


public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you set the permissions you need on the manifest? Try to run the app on your phone connected to your computer via USB cable, then copy the logcat error and put it in your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Don't do network I/O on the main UI thread. See the logcat for `NetworkOnMainThreadException` or any other problems.

Comment: application crushes with a stacktrace. Where is it?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is your real devices on the same network as the emulator. Can the real devices even access that address?

Comment: you doing network operation on main thread so the main cause is there

Comment: You mentioned that you are using mySQL to your app but I cannot see any code related to mySQL anywhere...I experienced the same problem a couple of months ago and it was because mySQL database wasn't on my phone but on the emulator.

Comment: please add the logcat report/stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer so i explain it for who will read this post later,

After android 3, we should use Asynctask for send and receive from webservice.

My emulator was android 2.2 and my device was android 4.4, so application worked perfect on emulator but crashes in device.

Answer (score 2):

The url for your webservice is local to your machine.
The emulator works fine because possibly it is on the same network.

But this url: http://192.168.10.110:2233/ cannot be accessed by your device.
That's why it is getting some timeout error and your application crashes.

If you want to test this on your device, maybe you need to use a common network or use wifi and some proxy tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Hope the issue is clear to you now.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my device and my virtual server are in the same network and same ip range, do you have another idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you given privileges to your application? Some security software will prevent you application from accessing network.

Answer (score 0):

in line

```
                 String result = Webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.10.110:2233/api/register", params);
```

you must get ipconfig for your device (phone) not use same ip config for your emu